# Automating the text in a text box for each slide of a Powerpoint

Tags: vba, automation, powerpoint

So I have about 500 pictures on each slide of a powerpoint. On the bottom corner of each slide I have a textbox. In the textbox, I want the name of the picture typed out. The name of the picture is the name of the image on the selection pane. So instead of typing out the name of the image in each textbox manually, I would like to automate this process.

Is there a way to do this? Is it possible to do this with VBA, and if so what would the code look like?

Comment: Note that SO is not a code-writing service. Please take the [tour] and see [ask].

Answer (score 0):

@BigBen is right. And yes, you can do it.

You need to use the `.Shape.Name` and the `TextFrame.TextRange.Text`
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/PowerPoint.Shape.Name
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/powerpoint.textrange